# Can I create a dynamic service description page in the MVC4 Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to create a dynamic page that shows the available api methods of a c# MVC4 web api?  I'm looking for something similar to the way the old soap .asmx page works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ASP.NET Web API help page - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/08/15/introducing-the-asp-net-web-api-help-page-preview.aspx

The Nuget package is here - http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage